# Create a new column when querying SQL Server

Tags: sql-server

I have two tables like this:

**Function**:

[image: Function]

**FunctionName**:

[image]

On query, I need to create a new column 'Status' where it will be 'true' if an AccountId has a function and 'false' if it is not in the function. What I mean is AccountId 1 has all the functions so basically I should get 'true' in all rows of the Function since AccountId 1 has all the functions and for AccountId 16, i should get 'false' in the Status column since there is no Function for AccountId 16. I really don't know how to implement this. I know how to Left join and stuff, I don't know how to go about what I need. Can you help? My feeble attempt got me to this is below but I know it's still a long way.

```
SELECT f.FunctionId, f.FunctionName,
CASE WHEN f.FunctionId IS NOT NULL THEN 'true' ELSE 'false' END AS [Status]
FROM [AccountFunction] as af
left join [Function] as f ON f.FunctionId = af.FunctionId
where af.AccountId = 1
```

Comment: Do we assign `true` to the status if an account has _all_ of the functions, or if it has _one or more_ of the functions?  This is not clear from your description.  Also, account 16 does not appear anywhere in your sample data.

Comment: AccountId 16 is really not there. So in the Status column of the temp_table I should get false for each of the Function. If AccountId 1 is lacking 1 function, I should get "false" in that row only and true in the other rows.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand your problem correctly, you want to assign a status of `true` whenever the function is present, and `false` whenever the function is absent.  If so, we can just use a `CASE` expression to determine the status.

```
SELECT *,
    CASE WHEN FuntionId IS NOT NULL THEN 'true' ELSE 'false' END AS Status
FROM yourTable;
```

Assuming you have an `Account` table containing all accounts, and you want to report the status for all accounts, then consider this query:

```
SELECT
    t1.AccountId,
    t2.AccountFunctionId,
    t2.FunctionId,
    CASE WHEN t2.FuntionId IS NOT NULL THEN 'true' ELSE 'false' END AS Status
FROM Account t1
LEFT JOIN FunctionName t2
    ON t1.AccountId = t2.AccountId;
```

Comment: Yes. That's what I mean. Do I use this with the temp_table I created?

Comment: Well that's really up to you.  You could just use the query to generate the `Status` column.  Or, you could add a formal new column to your table.

Comment: I like this better it's much simpler only I can't figure out how to use it. Is the "yourTable" which table is that? Function or the AccountFunction?

Comment: `yourTable` should be replaced with your own table, maybe a temp table, e.g. `#temp`.  The rest of the query should be recognizable to you.

Comment: With the changes I made to implement your  help, I get all the functions listed and it Status = 'true' but when I use the AccountId 16, I don't get any results at all. Please see my updated codes above.

Comment: @stackquestions I can't really help you with that.  If an account is missing entirely from your source table, then a regular query can't really generate missing information.  In this case, you should consider joining to another table which contains all accounts.  Then, we can report each account, even if your current table has that account missing.

Comment: Oh. Would that mean I need to include my third table, "Account", and use that?

Comment: I updated my answer to give you a rough idea of the type of query you may use.

Comment: Thank you for your time. I'll figure this out using your example.